# Does jQuery remove script tags returned by AJAX requests?

Tags: jquery

I'm performing an AJAX call in my jQuery-based JavaScript code. The response contains a `<script>` tag. However, it seems jQuery removes this tag.

Is this normal behavior of jQuery or XHR or a bug?

Answer (score 6):

It will depend on the `dataType` option you set in your AJAX call. If you set it to `html` it will give you back the HTML as plain text with the script tags ready for insertion to the DOM. If it is set to `script` then jQuery will attempt to run the script and return the result as a plain text string.

If you are not setting a `dataType` then jQuery will automatically infer the type from the response MIME type.

Have a look at the jQuery docs ( http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ ) for more info on the `dataType` setting.

Comment: thank you.i checked Content-Type in response header by firebug and it is text/html but there is no script tag in what is return from ajax.

Comment: You could try setting the `dataType` to 'text' to see if that helps. That will make jQuery return you the response as plain text with no processing.

Comment: thank you.i will try that.but at now,i see the script tag in response tab in firebug but not in the html tab of firebug.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your jQuery version.
I've tried 1.4 and will remove (but execute) `<script>`  while 1.9 will keep it.