# script block not include in ajax response

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

In my application I have a common layout for all the views, from one of the view(Index.cshtml) i have used `Ajax.BeginForm` to display another view as a response the code for this is

`@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Edit", "Home", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "content",InsertionMode=InsertionMode.Replace }))`

now my problem is as a response the edit view is rendered as expected but the script block with in the edit view is not included and hence the javascript is not executed.

`@model Test.Models.CARE`
   `@{`
    `ViewBag.Title = "Edit";`
`}`
`<script>`
    `function s() {`
        `alert("hi");`
    `}`
`</script>`
`<h2 style="padding: 0px; margin-top: 0px;">
    Edit</h2>`
`@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveForConfirmation", "Home"))`
`{`

Plz help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's bad practice to put javascript code in views, let alone partial views. So I would recommend you to externalize this javascript code in a separate function in a separate javascript file.

And then you could subscribe to the `OnSuccess` event of the Ajax.BeginForm helper:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Edit", "Home", new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "editSuccess", UpdateTargetId = "content", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }))
{
    ...    
}
```

and then define the `editSuccess` function in a **separate** javascript file:

```
function editSuccess(result) {
    alert('hi');
}
```

now in your partial view you should leave only what is supposed to be in a partial - markup. Get rid of any `<script>` tags, you don't need them. You don't need any inline scripts. They only increase the size of your webpages and waste bandwidth as they cannot be cached by the browsers:;

```
@model Test.Models.CARE
<h2 style="padding: 0px; margin-top: 0px;">Edit</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveForConfirmation", "Home"))
{
    ...
}
```

---

UPDATE:

If you have some poorly written javascript that depends on crap like ViewBag inside the partial then you could invoke the corresponding function from within the OnSuccess callback:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Edit", "Home", new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "s", UpdateTargetId = "content", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }))
{
    ...    
}
```

Notice how I have defined `OnSuccess = "s"` where `s` is the function that you have defined in your partial and which will be invoked in this case. But I repeat once again, this is a wrong approach and should only be used if you don't have time to refactor your code properly.

Comment: dear @Darin I know about your solution but my problem is that the javascript method which i want to call uses viewbag for some reason and hence can only be defined on runtime else will not funtion properly for example  function test(){var readonly = @Viewbag.Readonly; if(readonly){/*some code*/ }else{ /*some other code*/}}

Comment: Also this value of ViewBag is set in the controller method called by the Ajax and hence can't be defined before the method is executed

Comment: I understand. Well, in this case you could invoke the `s` function defined in your partial. See my updated answer.

Comment: there exactly lies the problem though the script block is defined in the partial view it is not included as the ajax response( while it is included when I use Html.Beginform)

Comment: Please see my updated response. You need to include `OnSuccess = "s"` in your `Ajax.BeginForm` helper so that it executes the `s` function that you have defined in your partial.

Comment: Dear @Darin I am very new to the programming world. I had a requirement that on some special case I have to disable controls of the view. I figured a way around to set up a viewdata and use it inside the javascript method to achieve the requirement. So, now I just want to ask what can be the best practice to achieve the functionality.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov This could be a question on it's own but may I ask how is it a bad practise to include js in views? 9 times out of 10 my javascript is view exclusive, going hand in hand with how the view is rendered. Are you suggesting every partial view and view should have it's own js file?

Comment: Yes, it is very bad practice to include javascript in views. It makes your views grow in size and your javascript can no longer benefit from automatic caching by the web browser. I agree that 9 out of 10 views javascript is view specific but that's not at all a reason to put it inside the view. This javascript should be placed in a separate javascript file. If you are putting it inside the view it means that you are doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Finally have achieved the required functionality.

this is how I have done it

View (from where the call was made)

```
<input type="submit" value="Create" />
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Edit", "Home", new AjaxOptions {OnSuccess="DisableControls()",
InsertionMode= InsertionMode.Replace,UpdateTargetId="DivToUpdate" }))
```

The Controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(FormCollection fc)
    {
        if (fc.Keys[0].ToString().TrimEnd() == "Display")
        {
            TempData["readonly"] = "readonly";
        }
        else
            TempData["readonly"] = "";
```

The Called Partial view

```
@model TestApp.Models.CUSTOMER
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}
<script>
function s() {
    var readonly="@TempData["readonly"].ToString()";
    if(readonly=="readonly")
       { 
       $('input[type="text"],select').attr('readonly','readonly');         
       $("#Save").remove();
       }
}
</script>
<h2 style="padding: 0px; margin-top: 0px;">
Edit</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Home"))
{


@Html.ValidationSummary()

<fieldset>
    <legend>CUSTOMER</legend>
    <table style="margin: 0px auto;">
        <tr>
            <td>
```

Now on diagnosing the cause for the previous failure attempt I wrote a `alert()` in the script to see whether the script is executing or not.

```
<script>
   function s() {
       var readonly="@TempData["readonly"].ToString()";var s="hi"+ prompt("name","");
       alert(s);
       if(readonly=="readonly")
          { //To make all text boxes and dropdown readonly
            $('input[type="text"],select').attr('readonly','readonly');         
            $("#Save").remove();//To Remove the save button
          }
       }
</script>
```

on further looking up with the firebug I could see that the response contains the script

```
<script>
function s() {
    var readonly="readonly";var s="hi"+ prompt("sdfs","kakaji");
    alert(s );
    if(readonly=="readonly")
       { 
       $('input[type="text"],select').attr('readonly','readonly');         
       $("#Save").remove();
       }
}
</script>
<form action="/Grid/Save" method="post"><div class="validation-summary-valid" data-valmsg-summary="true">  
<ul><li style="display:none"></li></ul>
</div>
<fieldset>
    <legend>CUSTOMER</legend>
    <table style="margin: 0px auto;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="editor-label">
```

But what found that the generated page doesn't include the script for which I found a reason [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5787280/does-jquery-remove-script-tags-returned-by-ajax-requests)

Hence this solves my problem and gave me a reason behind the fact that WHY I could not see or watch my script tag from the Ajax response.